# Removing only the first node of a TreeNodeCollection (Winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treenode

I have a `treeview` which is a collection of nodes that are extracted from an xmal file. Let's they are as:

```
-Rootnode
     -dir
     -choose
     -obj
     -nodecollections
         -Node1
           -node11
           -node12
               -node121
               -node122
        -Node2
           -node21
               -node211
        -...
```

What I am doing is that to create a node collection of `treenode` `Node1` and `Node2` etc(ignore the previous nodes in the `treeview` and only interest in last child) using

```
TreeNodeCollection compare1 = treeView1.Nodes[0].LastNode.Nodes;
```

which means I have now all children nodes from last child `nodecollections`.

Next I am checking one of its children, for example: `Node2` which I have all its children nodes saved in a new `Treenode`

```
TreeNode action_compare1 = treeView1.Nodes[0].LastNode.Nodes[indx_tree1];
```

where `indx_tree1` is an integer that I knew which node is selected and then I will save the node.

My aim is that after saving the selected node (which is done) then delete the first node of the selected node and then save them in a new node. For example, suppose `Node1` is saved in a TreeNode with name `First_node`. Then I will delete `Node1` from the Node structure and save it all children in a new node(I will not show in Treeview), in this case I will have the following saved nodes as new node `First_node`:

```
-node11
-node12
    -node121
    -node122
```

But I do not know how it can be done?

**Update:**

well maybe it is so clear the answer but I do not get it. then suppose I have he following node:

```
-Node1
    -node11
    -node12
        -node121
        -node122
```

Now I want to extract its all children in a new node. How can I do it?

Comment: I must admit that I don't get the idea... Might be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)... "How to do" questions tend to be misleading... Please describe what you want to achieve **without** your actual code, or please describe a real problem (with error message, code example...)

Comment: @Shnugo Please see the last paragraph of the edited version

Comment: What do you mean with "save"? The Nodes collection will show what ever you put there... Each Node has its own Nodes collection. The treeview expects one first node. So you might instantiate a new node and fill its Nodes collection with the nodes you want to display...

Comment: I meant just define new treenode and put in the `Lastnodes`. I do not want to display. I want to delete the first node and then put the children in a new node. Because after then I will do some computation on them.

Comment: If you do not want to display anything, just take the Nodes collection of Node1 in your case and that's it... If not, I still do not get your question...

Comment: I think Shungo is right: It seems your problem is that there really is no problem..

Comment: @Shnugo please see the update part.

Comment: Your update: Do you want to use the given nodes as they are (in this case: just use them), or do you want to work with copies of them (deep clone)?

Comment: Did you look at the Clone method? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.clone(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, Can you please give your idea as a answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to our discussion in the comments it came clear, that you need a "deep copy" of a child's Nodes collection.

You do this by calling the `Clone()` method of the given Node.

[Read about it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.clone(v=vs.110).aspx)

This is - in short - how you might use it:

```
TreeNode n=MyTreeView.Nodes[0];
var Node_and_SubNodes_of_given_Node = n.Clone();
```

Comment: But this command will only choose `Node[0]` not all children of it. For instance in the above example if we apply it for `Node1` then will choose only `node11` and its children. But I need to have `node12` as well.

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh, Did you try this? According to the documentation  `Clone()` will create a deep copy of the given node and **all its children**. You might try to query the parent's Node...

Comment: I did as you wished ;)

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh Thx a lot :-)